# Enabling both 32 and 64 bit Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, cmd

I recently installed both 32 and 64 bit JRE in my machine, but when I try to check using command prompt, it only detects the 64bit JRE.

java -d64 -version ->using this command outputs the version and all

java -d32 -version ->using this command just tells me that "this instance does not support 32-bit JVM"

More over, I tried to configure Java through the control panel (java control panel > java > view > user > add 32 bit JRE > Okay > Apply). I tried adding the 32 bit JRE, but after I press apply, then close the Java control panel window and reopen it, the 32bit JRE is no longer there.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?
Additional details: I'm using 64 bit windows 7.

Comment: Possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949091/switch-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-jdk-platform-on-windows-7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047063/having-access-to-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-jvm.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK The -d64 and -d32 only ever worked on Sparc Solaris.

If you have 64-bit JVM it will run all your programs unless they use a 32-bit shared library, in which case I suggest either a) don't do that or b) use the 32-bit JVM only when you need to by specifying the path.